# Stream intermediate operation -> IllegalStateException

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Well, I always thought that Java8 Stream intermediate operations don't do anything at all until a terminal operation operates on the stream.

So then why does this code throw an `IllegalStateException`?

```
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
s.limit(1);
s.limit(1);
```

Comment: _"intermediate operations don't do anything at all"_ That's not true. They create a new stream and link it with this stream. And since no two streams can depend on the same source stream you cannot invoke more than one operation. _"... until a terminal operation operates on the stream"_. Not **the** stream - **another** stream in the **pipeline**.

Answer (score 4):

You've hit a common misconception about `Stream`s. Due to their fluent API, the first instinct many developers have is that every method applied to a stream would just return it (similar, e.g., to how a `StringBuilder` acts - `myStringBuilder.append("Stack").append(" Overflow").append(" is").append(" is awesome!")`.

This however is not true. The various operations indeed return a `Stream`, but not the same object, and the error you're getting indicates that you attempted to apply two operations on the same object, which is illegal. If you use a purely fluent form, this would work as expected:

```
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3);
Integer i = s.limit(1).limit(1).findFirst().orElse(null); // returns 1;
```

Comment: Right, but that is not my point. The IllegalStateException says the Stream is closed or it has been operated on it. But why? I only used intermediate operations.

Comment: An intermediate operation still operates on a stream. Once you've had one, you cannot have another.

Comment: In which way does an intermediate operation operate on the stream? `s.peek(System.out::println).limit(1)` wouldn't print anything.

Comment: s.peek(System.out::println).limit(1) will,
but not, 
s.limit(1);
s.peek(System.out::println);

Comment: @kuhajeyan : No, s.peek(System.out::println).limit(1) won't. Give it a try.